# Why reference to array's object returns the object's address, not the value itself?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I've been studying arrays for a while and I struggle to grasp the idea behind these lines of code:

```
int array[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << "The address of the first element is " << &array[0];
```

Why reference in this case prints the address and not the value?
As far as I know reference access the value of the object being referenced, not its address.

Comment: that is not a reference - it is the address-of operator

Comment: The expression `array[0]` yields a reference to the element of the array(`int&`). Applying the address-of operator (unary `&`) on this reference results in a pointer to this element (`int*`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a = 24;
int& r = a; // <- when is part of a type (e.g `int&` here) `&` denotes a reference type

int* p = &a; // <- as an operator `&` is the address of operator
```